# SOAP request with multiple namespaces

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I send a POST request to generate AWB from a shipping company. In order to do that I have to POST multiple data entries via SOAP API POST request. The XML below is something similar which is required (I have simplified, it else It was asking for >30 parameters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PostaWebClient"
xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" name="Shipment_Creation">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:Shipment_Creation>
            <ns2:SHIPINFO>
                <ns1:ClientInfo>
                    <ns1:UserName>String</ns1:UserName>
                </ns1:ClientInfo>                
                <ns1:CodeShippmentType>SHPT2</ns1:CodeShippmentType>                 
            </ns2:SHIPINFO>
        </ns2:Shipment_Creation>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I achieve the same, I am using SoapClient and sending an array of parameters between "Shipment creation" tag but I get the error below

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Shipment_Creation'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 246.

I am new to SOAP, kindly help me go in the right direction, I would even highly appreciate code for above XML as it helps in understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `name="Shipment_Creation"` attribute in your `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` element. Just remove it.

You're already referring to the namespace in your element with `ns2`.

Comment: Thank you craigcaulfield, can you breif me how can I use PHP to generate the above XML data?

Comment: How are you generating the SOAP message now? Is it something you do, or do you receive it from another source?

Comment: I followed  a tutorial which used soap client, however that tutorial used simple xml without namespaces. I have posted a question previously, which contains my full code, its here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292326/soap-post-request-with-namespaces-php